# Set selectparameter from textbox in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, select, sqldatasource

```
<SelectParameters>
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox1" Name="model"  Type="String" />
            </SelectParameters>
```

My program actually works, I am just curious to find out why. I have a textbox with ID TextBox1 and a SqlDataSource that requires its value as a parameter in a query. So I set the source of the parameter as displayed above. I also have a button near the textbox, a click on which sets the value of the parameter. Why is that? The button has no onclick event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because clicking the button causes a postback to occur and your `SelectCommand` in the SqlDataSource gets re-constructed and if you've entered anything in the textbox it appends this value to the query.

After this happens your databound control (grid view,details view) refreshes displaying new values.

It's not magic, you just need to understand that ASP.NET is stateless and every time a postback occurs the page goes through the [ASP.NET Page life cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and your controls are re-created